# how to creat new list with every two elements from lentgh of initial list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, append

I have one list.

Length of list is variable

```
x=[25,100,63,138,103,178,125,195...]
```

Length y1 and y2 must be equal x

I want it to add a number like 140 or 138 for every two list members

Output:

```
y=[140,140,138,138,140,140,138,138]
```

```
y1=[140,140,138,138,136,136,140,140]
```

Comment: length of y1 and y lists are equal x list

Comment: What do you mean? I understood nothing from your question.

Comment: x=[25, 100, 63, 138, 103, 178, 143, 218, 183, 258, 223, 298, 263, 338, 303, 378, 343, 418, 383, 458, 423, 498]
lenx=round(len(x)/4)
print(lenx)
y1=[]
for i in range(lenx):
    y1.append(140)
    y1.append(140)
    y1.append(138)
    y1.append(138)
    if len(y1)>=len(x):
        y1.pop(i)
        y1.pop(i-1)

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75416507/edit) your question if you have more information.  As it stands it is very unclear how `x` relates to `y` and `y1` and code is not meant for comments, especially an indentation-sensitive language like Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, here is a simple way to create the new list using list comprehension in one line of code.

```
x = [25, 100, 63, 138, 103, 178, 143, 218, 183, 258, 223, 298, 263, 338, 303, 378, 343, 418, 383, 458, 423, 498] 
y1 = [140 if i%4 < 2 else 138 for i in range(len(x))]

print(y1)
```

Gives:

```
[140, 140, 138, 138, 140, 140, 138, 138, 140, 140, 138, 138, 140, 140, 138, 138, 140, 140, 138, 138, 140, 140]
```